# In oracle SQL, is there a good way to break out the results of an aggregate by year or some other variable not in the select statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have 3 tables, A,B, and C (a xref between A and B with some additional data).

A:A_id,A_type,A_status,A_Start_Date,A_department
B:B_id,B_Date
C:A_id,B_id

I'm trying to find the average count of days between B_date and A_Start_Date, and then break it down by year, except for each A_id, I'm only concerned with the earliest dated B_id that it's linked to. Generally each A_id is paired with multiple B_ids.

I can write the query to give me the aggregate value for all rows, or fiddle with a date range in the where clause between runs to get the aggregate for a given year, or even pull all rows (which gives me A_id and A_Start_date paired with the minimum dated B_id and B_Date), but my use of the aggregate "MIN" to get the minimum date precludes also grouping by year (a substring pulling year from A_Start_Date).

Is there a way around this? A coworker suggested using a partition, but doesn't that also prevent using year later on in a group by?

Here's what I have for aggregating all records, with the where statement for grabbing specific years commented out. I'd like to be able to display results as an average for each year, or an average for each department,or both:

```
SELECT
TRUNC(AVG(A_START_DATE - MIN(B_DATE)),1) as Days_Between
FROM A
LEFT JOIN C ON c.A_id = A.A_id
LEFT JOIN B ON b.B_id = c.B_id
WHERE A.A_Type = 'PPP' AND
A.A_start_date IS NOT NULL
--AND (A.A_start_date > '01-JAN-2010' AND A.A_start_date < '01-JAN-2022')
GROUP BY A.A_id,A.A_START_DATE;
```

Is there a way of nesting the group by so I can still use the min aggregate and to lowest level, and then the avg aggregate at a higher level?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and think I've got what I need - is this the best way to handle?:

```
SELECT YEAR,TRUNC(AVG(DAYSBET),1)as Avg_Days_to_Settle FROM (SELECT distinct
  To_char(A.A_start_date, 'YYYY') Year,
  A.A_start_date - Min(B.B_date) over (partition by A.A_id, To_char(A.A_start_date, 'YYYY') daysBet
FROM
  A,
  B,
  C 
WHERE  
   C.A_ID = A.A_ID and
  B.B_ID = C.B_ID and
  A.A_TYPE = 'PPP' and
  A.A_START_DATE IS NOT NULL
 )
 GROUP BY YEAR
 ORDER BY YEAR
```